# Woo Commerce page styles changed

Tags: woocommerce, stylesheet

I noticed that a site that looked great when I sent it to my client now has style errors. I don't think she could have messed with the styles. Only my Woo Commerce pages are affected. When I go in and try to restyle, nothing happens. Are there some styles I need to override or something? Anyone know what's happening. I saw a solution on the Woo site but it didn't work for me or maybe I did something incorrectly.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/

My url is www.ravenrooststudio.com.

Thank you!

Comment: I understand that www.ravenrooststudio.com is the website which is wrong. Can we see the one that look right?

Comment: WooCommerce styles are loaded in such a way that overrides don't work. The best way is to use the default styles as a base (new style doc), disable the defaults, and then use your new style doc.

Comment: @Mike: The other pages in the site (the non-shop pages) are styled correctly. The shopping pages are the only ones that aren't styled right. I also had some styles that were specific to the shopping pages that can't be viewed on other pages.

Comment: @Aibrean: Thank you for your response. How do I disable the defaults?

Comment: Add this to your functions:`add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
`

Comment: I did this but it disabled every style which isn't what I wanted and the nice sizing of my product images and their grid arrangement fell apart. I took the line back out.